Seg fault for c++ program
Whenever I try to enter the name of the description of a movie, or anything else related to a string entry, it always seg faults. I can enter the name and genre of a movie fine.
#include "splashkit.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using std::stoi;
using std::to_string;

struct Review {
    string description;
    int rating;
};

struct Movie {
    string name;
    string genre;
    string description;
    Review reviews[100];
    int review_count;
};

// Database struct
struct Database {
    Movie movies[100]; // Array to hold movies, assuming max 100 movies
    string genres[100]; // Array to hold genres, assuming max 100 genres
    int ratings[100];
    int movie_count;
    int genre_count;
    int rating_count;
};

int read_integer(const string& prompt) {
    write(prompt);
    return stoi(read_line());
}

void add_movie(Database &db);
void view_all_movies(Database &db);
void view_details(Database &db, int movie_index);
void alter_movie(Database &db, int movie_index);
void add_review(Database &db, int movie_index);
void delete_movie(Database &db, int movie_index);
void list_movies_with_genre(Database &db);
void list_all_movies_above_desired_rating(Database &db);
void main_menu(Database &db);
void details_menu(Database &db, int movie_index);

// Function to add a new movie to the database
void add_movie(Database &db) {
    Movie new_movie;

    // Get user input for movie details
    write_line("Adding a New Movie:");
    write_line("Enter the name of the movie:");
    new_movie.name = read_line();

    write_line("Select the genre of the movie:");
    write_line("1. Action");
    write_line("2. Romance");
    write_line("3. Sci-Fi");
    write_line("4. Fantasy");
    int genre_choice;
    do {
        write_line("Enter your choice (1-4):");
        genre_choice = stoi(read_line());
        switch (genre_choice) {
            case 1:
                new_movie.genre = "Action";
                break;
            case 2:
                new_movie.genre = "Romance";
                break;
            case 3:
                new_movie.genre = "Sci-Fi";
                break;
            case 4:
                new_movie.genre = "Fantasy";
                break;
            default:
                write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.");
                break;
        }
    } while (genre_choice < 1 || genre_choice > 4);

    // Initialize description to an empty string
    new_movie.description = "";

    write_line("Enter the description of the movie:");
    new_movie.description = read_line(); // Store the description

    // Store the new movie in the database
    db.movies[db.movie_count++] = new_movie;
}

// Function to view all movies and select one for action
void view_all_movies(Database &db) {
    write_line("Movies in the Database:");
    if (db.movie_count == 0) {
        write_line("No movies found.");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < db.movie_count; ++i) {
            write_line(to_string(i + 1) + ": " + db.movies[i].name);
        }
        write_line("Enter the number of the movie you would like to select:");
        int movie_number;
        do {
            movie_number = stoi(read_line());
            if (movie_number < 1 || movie_number > db.movie_count) {
                write_line("Invalid movie number. Please enter a number between 1 and " + to_string(db.movie_count) + ":");
            }
        } while (movie_number < 1 || movie_number > db.movie_count);
        
        // Pass control to the details_menu for the selected movie
        details_menu(db, movie_number - 1);
    }
    // Return to the main menu after details_menu
    main_menu(db); // Update function call
}

void details_menu(Database &db, int movie_index) {
    Movie selected_movie = db.movies[movie_index];
    write_line("Details Menu for " + selected_movie.name + ":");
    write_line("1. View Details");
    write_line("2. Alter Movie");
    write_line("3. Add Review");
    write_line("4. Delete Movie");
    write_line("Enter your choice (1-4):");
    int choice;
    do {
        choice = stoi(read_line());
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                view_details(db, movie_index);
                break;
            case 2:
                alter_movie(db, movie_index);
                break;
            case 3:
                // Add Review
                add_review(db, movie_index);
                break;
            case 4:
                // Delete Movie
                delete_movie(db, movie_index);
                break;
            default:
                write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 4);
}

void main_menu(Database &db) {
    int choice = 0;
    do {
        write_line("Main Menu:");
        write_line("1. Add Movie");
        write_line("2. View All Movies");
        write_line("3. List Movies with Genre");
        write_line("4. List Movies above Desired Rating");
        write_line("5. Main Menu");
        write_line("Enter your choice (1-5): ");
        choice = stoi(read_line());
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                add_movie(db);
                break;
            case 2:
                view_all_movies(db);
                break;
            case 3:
                list_movies_with_genre(db); // Call the function to list movies with genre
                break;
            case 4:
                list_all_movies_above_desired_rating(db); // Call the function to list movies above desired rating
                break;
            case 5:
                // Main Menu (do nothing, loop will continue)
                break;
            default:
                write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 5.");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 5);
}

void view_details(Database &db, int movie_index) {
    Movie selected_movie = db.movies[movie_index];
    write_line("Details for " + selected_movie.name + ":");
    write_line("Genre: " + selected_movie.genre);
    write_line("Description: " + selected_movie.description);
    write_line("Reviews:");
    if (selected_movie.review_count == 0) {
        write_line("No reviews available.");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < selected_movie.review_count; ++i) {
            write_line("Review " + to_string(i + 1) + ": " + selected_movie.reviews[i].description);
            write_line("Rating: " + to_string(selected_movie.reviews[i].rating));
        }
    }
}

void alter_movie(Database &db, int movie_index) {
    Movie &selected_movie = db.movies[movie_index]; // Reference to the selected movie
    write_line("Select what you want to alter:");
    write_line("1. Name");
    write_line("2. Genre");
    write_line("3. Description");
    write_line("4. Review Description");
    write_line("5. Rating");
    write_line("Enter your choice (1-5):");
    int choice;
    do {
        choice = stoi(read_line());
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                write_line("Enter the new name:");
                selected_movie.name = read_line();
                break;
            case 2:
                write_line("Select the new genre:");
                write_line("1. Action");
                write_line("2. Romance");
                write_line("3. Sci-Fi");
                write_line("4. Fantasy");
                int genre_choice;
                do {
                    write_line("Enter your choice (1-4):");
                    genre_choice = stoi(read_line());
                    switch (genre_choice) {
                        case 1:
                            selected_movie.genre = "Action";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            selected_movie.genre = "Romance";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            selected_movie.genre = "Sci-Fi";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            selected_movie.genre = "Fantasy";
                            break;
                        default:
                            write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.");
                            break;
                    }
                } while (genre_choice < 1 || genre_choice > 4);
                break;
            case 3:
                write_line("Enter the new description:");
                selected_movie.description = read_line();
                break;
            case 4:
                if (selected_movie.review_count == 0) {
                    write_line("No reviews available to alter.");
                } else {
                    write_line("Select the review to alter:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < selected_movie.review_count; ++i) {
                        write_line(to_string(i + 1) + ". " + selected_movie.reviews[i].description);
                    }
                    int review_choice;
                    do {
                        write_line("Enter your choice (1-" + to_string(selected_movie.review_count) + "):");
                        review_choice = stoi(read_line());
                        if (review_choice < 1 || review_choice > selected_movie.review_count) {
                            write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and " + to_string(selected_movie.review_count) + ".");
                        }
                    } while (review_choice < 1 || review_choice > selected_movie.review_count);
                    write_line("Enter the new review description:");
                    selected_movie.reviews[review_choice - 1].description = read_line();
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if (selected_movie.review_count == 0) {
                    write_line("No reviews available to alter.");
                } else {
                    write_line("Select the review to alter:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < selected_movie.review_count; ++i) {
                        write_line(to_string(i + 1) + ". " + selected_movie.reviews[i].description);
                    }
                    int review_choice;
                    do {
                        write_line("Enter your choice (1-" + to_string(selected_movie.review_count) + "):");
                        review_choice = stoi(read_line());
                        if (review_choice < 1 || review_choice > selected_movie.review_count) {
                            write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and " + to_string(selected_movie.review_count) + ".");
                        }
                    } while (review_choice < 1 || review_choice > selected_movie.review_count);
                    write_line("Enter the new rating:");
                    selected_movie.reviews[review_choice - 1].rating = stoi(read_line());
                }
                break;
            default:
                write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 5.");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 5);
}

void add_review(Database &db, int movie_index) {
    Movie &selected_movie = db.movies[movie_index]; // Reference to the selected movie
    if (selected_movie.review_count >= 10) {
        write_line("Sorry, you can't add more than 10 reviews for a movie.");
        return;
    }
    write_line("Write a description about how you felt about the movie:");
    string review_description = read_line();
    write_line("Rate the movie from 1 to 10:");
    int rating;
    do {
        rating = stoi(read_line());
        if (rating < 1 || rating > 10) {
            write_line("Invalid rating. Please enter a number between 1 and 10:");
        }
    } while (rating < 1 || rating > 10);

    // Add the review to the selected movie
    selected_movie.reviews[selected_movie.review_count].description = review_description;
    selected_movie.reviews[selected_movie.review_count].rating = rating;
    selected_movie.review_count++;

    write_line("Review added successfully!");
}

void delete_movie(Database &db, int movie_index) {
    Movie &selected_movie = db.movies[movie_index]; // Reference to the selected movie

    // Shift movies to the left to fill the gap caused by deletion
    for (int i = movie_index; i < db.movie_count - 1; ++i) {
        db.movies[i] = db.movies[i + 1];
    }

    // Decrease the movie count to reflect the deletion
    db.movie_count--;

    write_line("Movie '" + selected_movie.name + "' deleted successfully.");
}

void list_movies_with_genre(Database &db) {
    write_line("Select the genre of movies you would like to see:");
    write_line("1. Action");
    write_line("2. Romance");
    write_line("3. Sci-Fi");
    write_line("4. Fantasy");
    
    int genre_choice;
    do {
        write_line("Enter your choice (1-4):");
        genre_choice = stoi(read_line());
        if (genre_choice < 1 || genre_choice > 4) {
            write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.");
        }
    } while (genre_choice < 1 || genre_choice > 4);

    string selected_genre;
    switch (genre_choice) {
        case 1:
            selected_genre = "Action";
            break;
        case 2:
            selected_genre = "Romance";
            break;
        case 3:
            selected_genre = "Sci-Fi";
            break;
        case 4:
            selected_genre = "Fantasy";
            break;
    }

    bool found = false;
    write_line("Movies with Genre '" + selected_genre + "':");
    for (int i = 0; i < db.movie_count; ++i) {
        if (db.movies[i].genre == selected_genre) {
            write_line(db.movies[i].name);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        write_line("No movies found with genre '" + selected_genre + "'.");
    }
}

void list_all_movies_above_desired_rating(Database &db) {
    write_line("Enter the desired rating (1-10):");
    int desired_rating;
    do {
        desired_rating = stoi(read_line());
        if (desired_rating < 1 || desired_rating > 10) {
            write_line("Invalid rating. Please enter a number between 1 and 10:");
        }
    } while (desired_rating < 1 || desired_rating > 10);

    bool found = false;
    write_line("Movies with Rating Above or Equal to " + to_string(desired_rating) + ":");
    for (int i = 0; i < db.movie_count; ++i) {
        bool rating_above_desired = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < db.movies[i].review_count; ++j) {
            if (db.movies[i].reviews[j].rating >= desired_rating) {
                rating_above_desired = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rating_above_desired) {
            write_line(db.movies[i].name);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        write_line("No movies found with a rating above or equal to " + to_string(desired_rating) + ".");
    }
}

int main() {
    Database db; // Create the database object
    main_menu(db); // Call the main menu function with the database object
    return 0;
}


Honestly never encountered this problem before. Its really annoying me. I've been told that it might have something to do with the library itself?

This doesn't look like a [mcve]

Initialize your variables.  Instead of int movie_count; member variable definition, use int movie_count{};.  I am surprised that you've never encountered using an uninitialized variable before, considering how many there are in this code.

Not a library issue, like most of the time it actually has to do with a bug in your code.
db.movies[db.movie_count++] = new_movie;

db.movie_count is uninitialised, so this statement has undefined behaviour. A segfault is one possibility for undefined behaviour.
You could just add
db.movie_count = 0;

to main but what you should do is write a constructor which initialises your database object correctly
Database::Database() : movie_count(0), genre_count(0), rating_count(0)
{
}

That's what constructors are for.

I've tried both solutions here, still to no success. Do I add the constructor to the Database struct? I tried adding it to that and nothing happened. The initialisation in main also didnt work.
Can i post the error message printed by the compiler at all? It is quite long, and I'm new to this site, but I'm run out of options trying to figure out a solution

@shzpes You can post the compiler error message, I'll take a look. If my solution didn't work, then I think you just have more than one bug, because the issue above is definitely a bug.

@shzpes The constructor code I posted is for an 'out of line' definition, if you want an inline definition (i.e. one defined inside the struct) then drop the Database:: part at the beginning.

Sorry john, may i ask how i upload the error compilation message? I've tried editting the answer above, but not sure if that's how I should go about it

@shzpes I would just add it to the comments here.

Its quite large, but ill write out one for each and see if that works. ld: Undefined symbols:
write_line(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator>), referenced from:
add_movie(Database&) in movies-b15c3c.o
It also mentions similar errors for alter_movie, view_details, list_movies_with_genre

@shzpes OK, so where do you think the definition of write_line is? Because it is not in the code above. That's what the error is saying, you have not defined the function write_line. But if earlier you were running the code and getting a segfault, you must have a definition of that function somewhere.

@shzpes In other words this is a completely unrelated problem to the one in your original question.

I'm not quite sure. I always assumed this was a feature with the splashkit library. I'm very shallow with my knowledge of these things, I'm still very new to everything here. I'm confused, however, since if write_line is undefined then how could it let me print all the text leading up the description entry for the movie? It allows me to enter the name of the movie, alongside choose from which genre its in, but never allows me to continue beyond that
Sorry If im being confusing, again I'm still extremely new

@shzpes Well that was my assumption also, but since splashkit is non-standard I have no way to know anything about that. Anyway assuming write_line is in the splashkit library this is not a code error, it's a build error. When you build you have to tell the compiler (somehow) to add in the splashkit library. You must have been doing that earlier because you got your code to successfully build earlier (even though it didn't run correctly).

Hi john, I appreciate the help and am in a massive flurry for getting to the bottom of this. If you're willing and able to, is there anyway I can contact you outside of this website to help me resolve the issues here? If not, I understand; I'm just really lost at what my options are in terms of solutions. I've asked some of my peers and they, too, could not find solutions

@shzpes I don't think there's anyway you could contact me. Also I'm not sure what help I could be since I'm not familiar with your environment. Unless it's something I've used before I'm not going to know the details of how you configure a build. I would just think about what is different now, to what you did before when you were able to build the code.

That's okay. It seems im able to build the program quite fine, these error messages only provide themselves whenever I run/debug the program. Otherwise, the build works and I am able to run the start of the program. I thought the errors presented were the cause of the seg fault, but after experimentation it seems like this is a different problem in and of itself. So could you help me solve the seg fault issue first? Are there any altercations to the code that I could make to ensure the viability of a constructor and to ensure it works as intended?

I'm guess you are using VSCode? When you pick run/debug that will automatically do a build before running or debugging your program. It seems that somehow you put VSCode into a state where the build it does prior to Run/Debug is different to the regular build. That's obvously an issue that you should fix.

As for the segfault issue I'm not sure. The constructor I wrote should fix one issue, of course you have the same issue with all your other counts, so review_count is also not initialised to zero prior to use. I was able to run your code (with my fix above) without getting a segfault.

Could you show me how you implemented the solution? I've tried adding it into the 'Database' struct. Is there anywhere else I need to put it? If you're able to run the code than im really confused

For an inline definition of the constructor all you need to do is add it to the Database struct like this struct Database { Database() : movie_count(0), genre_count(0), rating_count(0) {} ... }; but if you are not comfortable with constructors I would just use the other option db.movie_count = 0; in main. If you are still getting segfault then you just have a different bug somewhere else (as I said earlier).

When you said you were able to run the code without getting a segfault, was that just the start of the program or did you try adding a movie? I've also tried both solutions here but have had no success with either of them.

@shzpes No, I added a movie. One possible issue here is that you are not successfully building your code. So you are making code changes, but because of the build problems you are having those changes are not making it into a runnable program. That would explain why the changes don't seem to work. Obviously before you do any programming you must master your build environment, if that is not working reliably then you are just lost.

@shzpes What I recommend to test this idea is that you remove your main function (comment it out so you can restore it again later). Replace it with a main that just prints a message, see if you can build, run, and see that message displayed. Until you can be confident that you can make changes to your code and see them have an effect when you run the code, then there is no point in trying to fix bugs.
